# Beta badges not visible with name

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Because of the public beta, the beta batches are awarded. But I can't see them on the top row. They also don't appear with the username.

I see that they are visible with users already having a silver badge but not with other users.
Is this as designed or is it a bug?

**Update**
I got another badge today and it shows up. Maybe the beta badge is a bit shy.
Anyway, this one seems to be resolved.

Comment: I've noticed this also.  I wonder if it will show up after I earn another badge.

Comment: I got another badge today and it shows up. Maybe the beta badge is a bit shy.

Comment: I've got the same problem... my status bar at the top (and my Flair) only shows my copper badges (on the main site, not Meta) and not my Beta silver.

Comment: I'm still not seeing my silver badge beside my name.  Guess I just need to work on getting a new badge.

Comment: This is marked as status-completed now, but mine is still missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine showed up today.  Probably just need to update the cache somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Mine appeared on the parent site once I had received another badge.

I assume as I haven't got another badge yet on the meta site, it's still missing here.

Comment: Nobody has a beta badge on Meta so I think there aren't any to get.

Answer (score 0):

It appears when you get any notification, regardless of whether it's a badge or not.

I got mine when someone retagged one of my questions.

Edit:
Correction, I got awarded the badge, but my top row and Flair are still missing it.